# How to load a .proto file in protoregistry

Tags: go, reflection, protocol-buffers

I need to simply load the contents of a few `.proto` files directly as descriptor so I can manipulate them via reflection as per https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoregistry

From what I can gather, I need to

1. Load the contents of the file as a string.
2. Use `prototext` to Unmarshal the string into a `descriptorpb.FileDescriptorProto`
3. Initialize a `ProtoFileDescriptor` with that
4. Finally I can register the ProtoFileDescriptor in a registry.

Do I really need to jump through all of these hoops, or am I completely missing another API?

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else lands on this question:

```
func registerProtoFile(src_dir string, filename string) error {
    // First, convert the .proto file to a file descriptor set
    tmp_file := filename + "tmp.pb"
    cmd := exec.Command("protoc", 
        "--descriptor_set_out=" + tmp_file, 
        "-I"+src_dir  
        path.Join(src_dir, filename))

    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer os.Remove(tmp_file)

    // Now load that temporary file as a file descriptor set protobuf
    protoFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile(tmp_file)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    pb_set := new(descriptorpb.FileDescriptorSet)
    if err := proto.Unmarshal(protoFile, pb_set); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // We know protoc was invoked with a single .proto file
    pb := pb_set.GetFile()[0]

    // Initialize the File descriptor object
    fd, err := protodesc.NewFile(pb, protoregistry.GlobalFiles)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // and finally register it.
    return protoregistry.GlobalFiles.RegisterFile(fd)
}
```

Comment: were you able to find an easier way? I'd also expect that the API would make it easier to decode protobuf serialized messages by just loading proto files at the runtime.

Comment: @kentor, Well, I stopped looking once I had the code in the answer implemented.

Comment: You can use jhump's protoparse repository to parse programmatically in Go code straight from `.proto` files: https://github.com/jhump/protoreflect

Comment: @kentor - I was wondering the same thing. 3 years late but see my answer below for what I found.

Answer (score 1):

I was digging around trying to figure out a way to register proto files with protoregistry *without* using the protoc executable on the host machine. I came upon this code in open policy agent that does it with [bufbuild/protocompile](https://github.com/bufbuild/protocompile) (which describes itself as "*the spiritual successor to the github.com/jhump/protoreflect/desc/protoparse package*"):

https://github.com/open-policy-agent/conftest/blob/68e075c067f82f415a070ce019554894a8228cf7/parser/textproto/textproto.go#L101

In my case, I wanted to not only register messages and types with protoregistry but I also wanted to set up a generic service handler as described in [gRPC GO Single Generic Service Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65561125/grpc-go-single-generic-service-handler) so I modified the open policy agent code a bit:

```golang
func (s *server) registerServicesFromProtoFileDynamicpbNoProtoc(protoFileName string) error {

    // Skip this file if we already registered it.
    if _, err := protoregistry.GlobalFiles.FindFileByPath(protoFileName); err == nil {
        return nil
    }

    fh, err := os.Open(protoFileName)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("open file: %w", err)
    }
    defer fh.Close()

    handler := reporter.NewHandler(nil)
    node, err := parser.Parse(protoFileName, fh, handler)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("parse proto: %w", err)
    }

    res, err := parser.ResultFromAST(node, true, handler)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("convert from AST: %w", err)
    }

    fd, err := protodesc.NewFile(res.FileDescriptorProto(), protoregistry.GlobalFiles)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("convert to FileDescriptor: %w", err)
    }

    if err := protoregistry.GlobalFiles.RegisterFile(fd); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("register file: %w", err)
    }

    for i := 0; i < fd.Messages().Len(); i++ {
        msg := fd.Messages().Get(i)
        if err := protoregistry.GlobalTypes.RegisterMessage(dynamicpb.NewMessageType(msg)); err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("register message %q: %w", msg.FullName(), err)
        }
    }
    for i := 0; i < fd.Extensions().Len(); i++ {
        ext := fd.Extensions().Get(i)
        if err := protoregistry.GlobalTypes.RegisterExtension(dynamicpb.NewExtensionType(ext)); err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("register extension %q: %w", ext.FullName(), err)
        }
    }

    for svcNum := 0; svcNum < fd.Services().Len(); svcNum++ {
        svc := fd.Services().Get(svcNum)
        serviceName := string(svc.FullName())
        s.sdMap2[serviceName] = svc
        gsd := grpc.ServiceDesc{ServiceName: serviceName, HandlerType: (*interface{})(nil)}
        for methodNum := 0; methodNum < svc.Methods().Len(); methodNum++ {
            m := svc.Methods().Get(methodNum)
            gsd.Methods = append(gsd.Methods, grpc.MethodDesc{MethodName: string(m.Name()), Handler: s.GenericHandler})
        }
        s.grpcServer.RegisterService(&gsd, s)
    }

    return nil
}
```

My `server struct` was also modified from the generic service handler post above:

```golang
type server struct {
    tunnel.UnimplementedRequestTunnelServer
    sdMap                  map[string]*desc.ServiceDescriptor         // this uses the github.com/jhump/protoreflect/desc package that I didn't want to use
    sdMap2                 map[string]protoreflect.ServiceDescriptor  // Instead, I use the official protoreflect package
    grpcServer             *grpc.Server
}
```